# AngularJS - Add Class to Child Element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button, *as seen in example.html*, which resides inside an `ng-repeat` directive. As such, there are many more like it. **How can I add the class `fa-spin` to the child `i` element when `syncAccount()` is called and then remove the class `fa-spin`, from the same child element, at the end of `pullProfile()`?**

*-----example.html*

```
<md-button class="md-raised md-default" ng-click="syncAccount(account.username)">
    <i class="fal fa-sync"></i> Re-sync
</md-button>
```

*-----example.controller.js*

```
$scope.syncAccount = function(username)
{
    console.log('syncing ' + username + ' ...')
    $scope.pullProfile(username)
}

$scope.pullProfile = function(username)
{
    // do stuff
    // remove the fa-spin class
}
```

I have tried using `angular.element().closest()` without success. Example:

*-----example.html*

```
<md-button class="md-raised md-default" ng-click="syncAccount($event, account.username)">
    <i class="fal fa-sync"></i> Re-sync
</md-button>
```

*-----example.controller.js*

***(UPDATED to reflect solution as suggested by chiliNUT in the comments)***

```
$scope.syncAccount = function($event, username)
{
    var spinElement = angular.element($event.currentTarget).find('.fa-sync')
    spinElement.addClass('fa-spin')

    console.log('syncing ' + username + ' ...')
    $scope.pullProfile(spinElement, username)
}

$scope.pullProfile = function(spinElement, username)
{
    // do stuff
    spinElement.removeClass('fa-spin')
}
```

***Aside:***

Using `.find('i')` did not work as `.find()` is limited to lookups by tag name only. See here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: That's not how `closest` works. Instead of `.closest('i')` try `.find('i')`

Comment: In the context of my example, `.find('i')` did not return anything. `.find('.fa-sync')` worked though, which has the same effect. If you post as answer, i'll mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: Please, don't use jQuery based solutions in Angular. It is a very bad fashion.

Comment: `angular.element().find()` is a function of AngularJS's jqLite and does not require jQuery explicitly. Since jqLite is already a part of Angular, I see no reason it cannot be used here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<md-button class="md-raised md-default" ng-click="syncAccount($event, account.username)">
    <i class="fa {{ syncInProgress ? 'fa-spin' : 'fa-sync' }} "></i> Re-sync
</md-button>
```

In controller

```
$scope.syncInProgress = false;
$scope.syncAccount = function(index) {
    $scope.syncInProgress = true;
};
```

After sync pls change the value of `syncInProgress` to `false`

Comment: Thank you, however the button resides within an ng-repeat directive and as such, many buttons exist in one view. I believe this would result in conflicts by using a single boolean variable `$scope.syncInProgress`.